# List in python to output mapped nodes

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this `['AC', 'AF', 'CF']`

I want the output to be `[A,C,F]`

For example, if the input is : `['AC', 'AD', 'CD']`, then I want the output as `[A,C,D]`.

**Question**

What is an understandable way to get it?

Comment: What is the correlation between your input and output?  Can you post your code so that we get an understanding of what you attempted so far?

Answer (score 2):

If all you are looking for is a list of all unique characters in your input, you can do something like this:

```
sorted(list(set(''.join(['AC', 'AF', 'CF']))))
```

This works by turning your input into a single string and then converting that string to a set, which will remove duplicates. We then convert that set back to a list and sort it.

The output of the above example is:

```
['A', 'C', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
s = ['AC', 'AF', 'CF']
final_data = list(set(list(itertools.chain(*map(list, s)))))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'C', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set()` on the string of the `list`, then sort the set using `sorted()`:

```
>>> a_list = ['AC', 'AF', 'CF']
>>> sorted(set(''.join(a_list)))
['A', 'C', 'F']
>>> b_list = ['AC', 'AD', 'CD']
>>> sorted(set(''.join(b_list)))
['A', 'C', 'D']
```

Note, `sorted()` returns a `list`.

Since you are asking *what is an understandable way to get it*, this is what is happening at each step:

```
>>> a_list = ['AC', 'AF', 'CF']
>>> ''.join(a_list)  # Concatenation of the strings in the list
'ACAFCF'
>>> set(''.join(a_list))  # Set is an unordered collection of unique elements
{'A', 'F', 'C'}
>>> sorted(set(''.join(a_list)))  # List of all the items in the above set in ascending order
['A', 'C', 'F']
```